# C# - Is it possible to make excel files readonly / non-editable / password protected using Compact Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, excel, compact-framework, readonly, .net-cf-3.5

So, I have this console (from Beijer - uses ixDeveloper) and it uses CF 3.5.

It is somewhat limited, so I am trying to do what I can with scripts (in C#).

Right now, I have an Excel file regarding an Audit Trail and it has to be non editable. I can convert it into a pdf, but it takes about 15 minutes to convert.

If I could just make the excel file not editable, my problem would be solved.
Is there a way to do that?

I installed the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll, but it does not seem to work, it gives a class not registered error

Comment: With console you mean a piece of hardware not the console a developer normally has in mind when reading that word?

Comment: Yes @Ralf, I mean a console/panel as a piece of hardware. Sorry if I wan't clear

Comment: Then i don't see how the interop stuff helps you. It interacts with a locally installed Excel and you can't install Excel on that hardware(or can you?). Or is that some Client/Server thingy and all the needed logic is somewhere else and the talk about Compact Framework/Hardware is just a distraction?

Comment: @KJ i think you interpreted to much into the readonly requirement. Its an audit trail so presumably its only about the fact that it should not be possible to be tampered. Presumably he rather needs a digital signature then write protection.